# Angular Ivy compiler error for production build

Tags: angular, angular8, devextreme, devextreme-angular, angular-ivy

I am working on this Angular 8 application and I am getting the following error while trying to create production build by running `ng build --prod`.

```
ERROR in Unable to write a reference to DxiItemComponent in D:/workspace-venio/VenioWebMain/WebMain/OnDemand/app_src/node_modules/devextreme-angular/ui/nested/item-dxi.js from D:/workspace-venio/VenioWebMain/WebMain/OnDemand/app_src/node_modules/devextreme-angular/ui/
accordion.js
```

I have enabled Ivy,

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": true,
},
```

The DexExtreme library I am using is,

```
"dependencies": {
    "devextreme": "^19.1.5",
    "devextreme-angular": "^19.1.5",
}
```

The issue might be related to [this reported issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29361). Any sort of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just so that it might help somebody else,

I figured out that DevExtreme at the version I was using didn't support Ivy. I upgraded to a recent beta version and the application builds up correctly now. Here are the versions I am currently using:

```
"devextreme": "^19.2.2-beta",
"devextreme-angular": "^19.2.2-beta"
```